# If conditions with hebrew letter

Tags: php, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split the first letter from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858706/split-the-first-letter-from-variable)

i have code:

```
if($firstletter=='I')
{
     $picture = ImageCreateFromPNG ($global['maleBackgroundImages'][5]);
}
else
{
     $picture = ImageCreateFromPNG ($global['maleBackgroundImages'][4]);
}
```

If I want to change the 'I' to hebrew letter how I do it?
and if I want to check range

```
$firstletter>a **and** $firstletter<b
```

how I do it in the if?

Comment: Is it possible to have a letter that lies between a and b?

Comment: if($firstletter=='א') its possible?

Comment: and if($firstletter<'c'&&$firstletter>'a') it's possible?

Comment: Idan - if($firstletter=='א') is perfectly possible.... but how are you getting $firstletter

Comment: $firstletter = $userData['name'][0];

Answer (score 1):

Assuming UTF-8 character set

```
$firstletter = mb_substr($userData['name'], 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
if ($firstletter=='א') {
    ...
}
```

or modify for the appropriate character set

Comment: thank you mark, but if I do it and I comper also with english letter is ok?

Comment: It isn't ok, no.... א !== a, to make that type of a comparison you'd need to convert your hebrew characters to english characters

Comment: no, you dont understand me, i mean if I write after the if more if with $firstletter=='a' it's ok?

Comment: You mean if ($firstletter=='א' || $firstletter=='a') { then yes, that's OK

Comment: and if I write if($firstletter>'a' && $firstletter<'c') it's possible?